# Multiple charts by groups in column

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have the following dataset (in practice, the dataset contains more names and dates per name):

```
Name    Date    Value1  Value2
AA  01-02-2022  0.5744  10
AA  01-03-2022  0.5542  10
AA  01-04-2022  0.5551  10
AA  01-05-2022  0.5678  10
BB  01-02-2022  0.5518  11
BB  01-03-2022  0.5659  11
BB  01-04-2022  0.5455  11
BB  01-05-2022  0.5404  11
CC  01-02-2022  0.5524  12
CC  01-03-2022  0.5321  12
CC  01-04-2022  0.5554  12
CC  01-05-2022  0.5407  12
```

I want to create a chart for each name in column "Name". One chart for AA, another chart for BB and a third chart for CC.

The charts should plot Value1 and Value2 on the Y-axis against Date on the X-axis.

The data is loaded into the spreadsheet using a power query, which extracts data from an Oracle database.

If possible, I would like to place the charts next and/or appended to each other.

As names are regularly removed (added) to the dataset, I am looking for a dynamic solution and hope to solve this using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses a dictionary to keep the unique names as key and range first row, respectively, last row as items, then builds `DataSource` based on them:

```vb
Sub TestInsertCClusteredChart()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrIt, i As Long, dict As Object
    Dim rngDS As Range, ch_shape As Shape, chLeft As Double, chTop As Double
  
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
    arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value2
  
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'dict.RemoveAll
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(i)
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1))
            If UBound(arrIt) = 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve arrIt(1)
                arrIt(1) = i
            Else
                arrIt(1) = i
            End If
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt
        End If
    Next i
  
    chLeft = sh.Range("F2").left: chTop = sh.Range("F2").top 'positions of the first chart
    'build dataSource range and insert chart:
    For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        Set rngDS = Union(sh.Range("A1:D1"), sh.Range(sh.cells(dict.Items()(i)(0), "A"), sh.cells(dict.Items()(i)(1), "D")))
        Set ch_shape = sh.Shapes.AddChart2  'insert the chart
        With ch_shape.Chart
            With .ChartArea
                .left = chLeft
                .top = chTop
            End With
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData rngDS
            chLeft = chLeft + .ChartArea.width 'calculate the left position for the next chart
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Sub deleteCharts(sh As Worksheet)
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In sh.Shapes
        If s.HasChart Then s.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

The chart is created using default dimensions (height, width). They can be set, of course.

Comment: Thank you, @FaneDuru - your answer was exactly what I was hoping for. I wouldn't have been able to come up with this solution myself. Thank you for also providing a description of your code logic. 
I will use your code as a standing point and make the necessary modifications. 
In this regard, I hope you dont mind me asking about how to include the following modifications: 
1) In the charts, names and dates are specified on the x-axis. Would it be possible for only the dates to appear on the x-asis and, maybe, place the name in the title instead?

Comment: 2) Is it possible to place three charts next to each other, such that the fourth chart is placed below the first. The same logic would then apply to the seventh chart, etc.

Comment: I am driving.....

Comment: @Cecilie S. K Addapeted the code. Please, test it and send some feedback. I will also like to read an explanation related to accepting/not accepting the answer...

Comment: Thank you, @FaneDuru . The code is now perfect! I'm so sorry - that was a mistake of mine. It was never my intention to "unaccept" the answer.

Comment: Hi again.  I think there may be a problem with the code. Whenever I refresh the query, the plot for e.g. name A also contains data points for name B. Is there some way to circumvent this and to ensure that plot A only contains data points for A? Thank you.

Comment: @Cecilie S. K I am afraid I am not able to get you... Why this to **be a problem with the code**? If you refresh the query and some other data are brought/inserted, do you expect the **existing charts** to not be influenced? If so, this is not possible. The charts have like source a UNION range, which most probably is changed by refreshing in discussion. You should **run the code again**. It deletes the existing  charts and creates others adapted to the existing situation... Is it something I am missing about the issue?